# Programmatically set column labels in HTMLChart

Tags: c#, telerik, radhtmlchart

See [Telerik column chart demo here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/htmlchart/examples/charttypes/columnchart/defaultcs.aspx). Notice the labels above each column, such as "25000 sales". Now notice in the declarative code how this label is set:

```
<LabelsAppearance DataFormatString="{0} sales" Position="OutsideEnd"></LabelsAppearance>
```

I either need to set DataFormatString programmatically, or (better yet) I need to set it to the value of a column in my dataset from sql server. This column's data is not on the chart currently because I ONLY want that column's data used at the label at the top of each column. I can't figure out how to do either. How is it done?

Answer (score 1):

By using the ClientTemplate: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/htmlchart/functionality/clienttemplate/overview

You can set it in the markup or the code-behind:

```
                    <telerik:ColumnSeries>
                        <LabelsAppearance>
                            <ClientTemplate>
                                  #=dataItem.someColumn#
                            </ClientTemplate>
                        </LabelsAppearance>
                    </telerik:ColumnSeries>
```

or for an already existing chart:

```
(RadHtmlChart1.PlotArea.Series[0] as ColumnSeries).LabelsAppearance.ClientTemplate= "#=dataItem.someColumn#";
```

where of course you can access the series any way you like.